# Breezejs id fix-up after save changes

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm creating new entity using breeze in this way:

```
var item = manager.createEntity("ExercisesAndMuscles", initialValues);
 saveChanges().fail(addFailed);
 logger.log("id is", item.Id);

function saveChanges() {
        return manager.saveChanges();

    }
```

And in console is -1, and according to Breeze documentation this is as it should be. And when I refresh page I see that id is not -1 anymore, i.e. now id is permanent id form database.

So my question is, how can I get this id automatically i.e. without refreshing page.
I know that one possible solution would be to generate ids on client side, but I'd rather not do that.

Are there any other ways ? And if generating id on client side is only way, what would be proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveChanges occurs asynchronously, so at the time that you are logging the id is indeed -1 but some time shortly thereafter it becomes permanent.

```
var item = manager.createEntity("ExercisesAndMuscles", initialValues);
saveChanges().then(showId).fail(addFailed);

function showId () {
    logger.log("id is", item.Id);
}

function saveChanges() {
    return manager.saveChanges();
}
```

log the id after the returned promise is completed like shown and it will no longer be -1.